# How to match different tenses of the same english verb in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, wordnet, linguistics

Is there a way to use something like WordNet but instead of just synonyms (wn_s.pl file) be able to match all of the tenses of a verb: "be","was","is","will be" etc using ElasticSearch? A stemmer wouldn't work for irregular verbs like be, while it might work for regular ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer and tested it! I had to install the elastic-morphology plugin which is based on Lucene morphology for english: https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-analysis-morphology

Comment: Hey, I know this is a quite old question, but I'm wondering if this plugin solved the problem successfully. I'm researching it because I need similar functionality but the plugin's docs aren't that good. Thanks!

Comment: back then when I used it, it definitely improved the matches of verbs for english when they were in different tense than the query.  If that doesnt work well enough then you need other methods with stemming and more manual work: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/languages.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try then.